# Nodejs and postgresql and promises and ES6

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm pretty new to nodejs, I use just ES6 and I massively use generators.
I'm trying to promisfy the "connect" and "query" function of pg module.
Why the following snippet doesn't release the main execution context and keeps the script running from shell? It works correctly but it hangs after printing the result.

Disclaimer: I'm not interested in Bluebird.promisfy function nor pg-promise, knex and bookshelf modules. None of these fits my needs.

```
'use strict';

let co = require('co');
let pg = require('pg').native;

function connect(hostname, username, password, database) {
    let connectionString = `postgres://${username}:${password}@${hostname}/${database}`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pg.connect(connectionString, function(error, result, done) {
            if(error)
                return reject(error);
            else
                return resolve({ connection: result, release: done });
        });
    });
}

function query(connection, text, values) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(text, values, (error, result) => {
            if(error)
                return reject(error);
            else
                return resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

co(function*(){
    try {
        let hostname = 'localhost';
        let username = 'damiano';
        let password = 'damiano';
        let database = 'graph';

        let client = yield connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'graph');
        let result = yield query(client.connection, `select * from vertices v1, vertices v2 limit 1`);
        client.release();
        return result;
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result.rows);
    return;
});
```

Edit:
Ok the connection was hanging. The done method doesn't seem to do nothing, there is a hidden method .end on the connection itself.

Comment: Try adding `process.exit(0)` when the job is done

Comment: Isn't it a "rude" solution? No other clean way to close the execution without explicit exit?

Comment: Hm, never though of this as a 'rude' solution, but I found this as the only working one when using promises.

Comment: I want to avoid a forced exit. I think there is something hanging but I cannot understand what: the pool is released, promises are fullfilled, exceptions and errors are handled.

Comment: My gut feeling is that it has to do something with promises themselves, because I didn't experience this when using callbacks

Comment: Have a look a this, both generator and promise version let the script close flawlessly:
'use strict';

let co = require('co');

let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 setTimeout(function(){
  resolve('ciao');
 }, 1000);
});

/*
p.then(result => {
 console.log(result);
});
*/

co(function*(){
 return yield p;
}).then(result => {
 console.log(result);
});

Comment: Ok the connection was hanging. The done method doesn't seem to do nothing, there is a method .end on the connection itself.

Comment: `None of these fits my needs.`. What are those that you must reinvent the wheel? [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) for one thing, [supports generators](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#generators).

Answer (score 0):

Even since it is not answer for exact question, I'm still gonna recommend something different. I successfully use for this sequilizejs with koa and co. Sequilize's methods return promises, so I yielding them directly `let rows = yield table.findAll({ where: { age: 18 }, raw: true });` And I dont have to worry about connections.

Comment: thanks sergey! the problem is I'm gonna make a heavy use of jsonb data, for any kind of query and none of the current libraries have a great support for that. Therefore I decided to go on my own.

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but maybe this gonna help. JSONB support in sequilize http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#jsonb. And also http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/. I'm not a sequilize developer, I'm just feeling your pain when see as you going to manage connection pool yourself. It is unnecessary extra work novadays.

Comment: Thanks sergey for mentioning that. Even Sequelize hasn't great support for jsonb: ok basic where conditions, but what about updating single jsonb fields and joining on them? A step forward must be done.